# An Inequality with Exponential Terms

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

I am trying to understand why an inequality in the following post is true: [Bounding rows of random matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4120560/bounding-rows-of-random-matrices/4123276#4123276).

In particular, I am wondering why we have

$$
\exp\left(-\frac{t^2/2}{2np+t/3}\right)\le \exp\left(-\frac{Ct^2}{np}\right)+\exp(-Ct)
$$

for some absolute constant $C$. Here $t > 0$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $p \in (0, 1]$. Perhaps this follows from the convexity of exp, but I am not seeing how after a couple attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its much simpler than convexity. $$ \exp\left( - \frac{t^2/2}{2np + t/3}\right)\le \exp\left( - \frac{t^2}{2\max(2np, t/3)}\right) = \exp\left(- \min\left( \frac{t^2}{4np} , \frac{3t}{2} \right) \right)\\
 \le \exp\left( - \min\left( \frac{t^2}{4np}, \frac{t}{4}\right)\right)\le \exp( - t^2/4np) + \exp(-t/4),$$ so the claim holds with $C = 1/4$.