# Why is Bernstein's Inequality legal here?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, inequality, solution-verification

This is a follow up question based on this post: [Bounding rows of random matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4120560/bounding-rows-of-random-matrices/4123276#4123276).

I can not see why we can use Bernstein's inequality as mentioned in the answer. In particular, it seems like the variables $(\delta_{ij} - p)^2$ are not centered: $\mathbb{E}(\delta_{ij} - p)^2 = (1 - p)p$. Therefore, Bernstein's inequality can not be directly applied. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can show that there exists constants $C,D > 0$, such that for a sub-exponential variable $X$, you have $C\|X\|_{\Psi_1} \leq \|X - \mathbb E X\|_{\Psi_1} \leq D \|X\|_{\Psi_1}$.

Comment: @YongyiYang I understand we can center a subexponential variable and still keep it subexponential. But the Bernstein’s concentration inequality only applies to the centered variable, right? It is subexponential, but that alone is not enough to use the concentration inequality.

Comment: You are right, but generally for any sub-exponential variable, you can first centerize it, then use bernstein's inequality, and then shift back.

Comment: @YongyiYang I see. Could you explain why the lower bound holds here? I would assume a similar statement hold for subgaussian?

Comment: Sorry, that lower bound was actually wrong, but you can shift the tail inequality you obtained, i.e. $\mathbb P(X- \mathbb EX \leq t) \implies \mathbb P(X \leq t + \mathbb E X)$. And I think this is exactly what the post you referred to was doing.